# Can I have some different color on candle-stick if opening and closing values are same in OHLC?

Tags: javascript, charts, trading, candlestick-chart, lightningchart

OHLC chart is showing candlestick either in red (if opening value is greater than closing value) or else green. Using LightningChartJS is it possible to have a different color (like grey) for a bar with same opening and closing value? Currently it is showing it in green.

```
.setPositiveStyle( (figure) => figure
                    .setStrokeStyle( (stroke) => stroke.setThickness(2) )
                   )
  .setNegativeStyle( (figure) => figure
                    .setStrokeStyle( (stroke) => stroke.setThickness(2) )
                   )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*OHLCSeries.setStyle()* can be used to specify a styler common to both positive and negative figures. You should be able to check for equal opening and closing values inside the styler and act accordingly.

```
OHLCSeries.setStyle(( candlestick ) => {
    if ( candlestick.getClose() === candlestick.getOpen() ) {
         // Apply special style to candlestick.
    }
})
```